# Why are my images not showing up in the nodes of this D3 chart?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/SCb7T/

Code:

```
var width = 500,
    height = 500;

var dotSize = 50;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-10020)
    .linkDistance(dotSize)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var graph = {
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Name","group":1},
    {"name":"Name","group":2},
    {"name":"Name","group":3},
    {"name":"Name","group":4}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":1}
  ]
};


force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

 var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", dotSize)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

node.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://lorempixel.com/64/64/cats")
    .attr("x", -32)
    .attr("y", -32)
    .attr("width", 64)
    .attr("height", 64);

node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't append `image` to `circle` elements -- the SVG spec doesn't allow this. Instead, append the images directly and set `transform` on them in the `tick` function instead of `cx`/`cy`.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SCb7T/2/).